# what should I do to make admin service work in Django 1.2

Tags: django, admin, django-csrf

It worked great before.

And now when I'm trying to go to /admin/ I have a mistake:

```
Module "django.contrib.auth.context_processors" does not define a "csrf" callable request processor
```

I read this: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/

Now in my settings are:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfResponseMiddleware',
)
```

What I have to do to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

To make it work I had to write it in different order:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)
```